# Implementing multiple selection on TreeView using checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

How do I make it so that when a user selects a tree node, all of the ones under it will be selected? Is this something I am missing in the properties, or do I have to code this?

Comment: Your comments to Nickolay's answer indicate that you're using checkboxes on your `TreeView`. Is that assumption correct, or are you trying to make multiple items appear selected (i.e., highlighted)? Multiple selection is a way bigger hassle if you don't want to use checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, I am using checkboxes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you should code that, it's quite simple, just handle OnChange event of tree node, and set .Checked to all it's siblings.

Comment: well then how do I handle a "half checked" kind of thing? Like where only some of the children are checked and so the parent usually has a box in it?

Comment: That can be also handled via OnChecked event, just update value of parent nodes to checkState.Indeterminate if not all of it's siblings are checked.